# How do I get gradle to load all dependency versions

Tags: gradle

I have a non-java project with dependencies, and we basically want to be able to include two versions of the same dependency module from Artifactory into the workspace of the project (in different folders).

So I have a project with multiple versions of the same module in the dependency tree. For example:

```html
Project A depends on: 
       module B version 3.0 depends on
                          module C version 2.0
       module C version 1.0
```

Which I want to expand to:

```html
workspace
    dependencies
        B              <- contents of module B version 3.0
        C_abc          <- contents of module C version 2.0
        modC_xyz       <- contents of module C version 1.0
```

Now we want gradle to get the artifacts from artifactory for both version 1.0 and 2.0 of module C.
The problem is that it tries to resolve the 'conflict' (i.e. it wants to get version 1.0 or version 2.0, and I cannot seem to get it to just keep both. 
Once I have them all available in the configuration, I can expand them into the right folder, so that is not the real issue.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate configuration for the duplicate module. You can then copy that configuration to a location of your choice.

```
configurations {
    moduleB
}

dependencies {
    moduleB 'org.foo:dependency:3.0'
}

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from(configurations.moduleB) {
        into 'workspace/dependencies/B'
    }
}
```